# peewee multiple database with "Using" decorator

Tags: python, decorator, using, peewee, multiple-databases

In the peewee [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/2.10.2/peewee/database.html#using-multiple-databases), it says you can harness multiple databases with "Using "decorator

```
master = PostgresqlDatabase('master')
read_replica = PostgresqlDatabase('replica')

class Data(Model):
    value = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = master

with Using(read_replica, [Data]):
    # Query is executed against the read replica.
    Data.get(Data.value == 5)

    # Since we did not specify this model in the list of overrides
    # it will use whatever database it was defined with.
    SomeOtherModel.get(SomeOtherModel.field == 3)
```

In the above example, you can use multiple databases with "Using" decorator.

My question is how to import "Using" decorator?

I cannot find any code about importing the Using decorator.

Comment: That documentation is for peewee 2.0, which is quite old. The preferred way to do this now is http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.bind_ctx

Answer (score 1):

You are on the 2.x docs, try using the version of docs to match the version of peewee you are using. The way to do this since 3.0 is with the bind() and bind_ctx() methods:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.bind_ctx

```
master = PostgresqlDatabase('master')
read_replica = PostgresqlDatabase('replica')

class Data(Model):
    value = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = master

with read_replica.bind_ctx([Data]):
    # Query is executed against the read replica.
    Data.get(Data.value == 5)

    # Since we did not specify this model in the list of overrides
    # it will use whatever database it was defined with.
    SomeOtherModel.get(SomeOtherModel.field == 3)
```